# Different validation on Model depending on Page

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, razor, annotations

I have a Details Model that is used in 2 different pages.

```
public class Details
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
}
```

When saved in the **1st Page**, I want every property of this model to be required, however when saved in the **2nd Page**, I want every property to be optional.
Is there a way to make this validation conditional depending on the page I use it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming details model is a base class for these two separate views. You should make it abstract and derive from it (unless you do need to use it somewhere) or use automapper to map details model into details-1 and details-2 with the required validation attributes